# QGIS: latitude coordinates are reversed; map upside down

Tags: latitude-longitude, gdal, netcdf, qgis

I have been using QGIS to display a map of the long term precipitation average of the Netherlands. However, when QGIS opens the data, the map is shown upside down

[image]

I noticed that the coordinates are displayed from **0 - 266 (lon)** and **-315 - 0 (lat)**. I figured that the latitude is projected upside down

[image]

In stead of **-315 - 0** it should be **0 - 315** and the map should look fine. But I can't figure out how to inverse this value. 
The file is a NetCdf file. I openend the XML metadata QGIS made for me with EmEditor, but it did show the right coordinates (in lat/lon), So I think it has something to do with the way QGIS sets up the map or the way it converses the lat/lon to meters.
Anybody who encountered the same problem as me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Micha (see the comments):

I was told to solve the problem using GDAL (Geospatial Data Abstraction Library), a method to look into and translate/process metadata. This was quitte hard to understand, while I am relatively new in programming and using powerfull 'languages' like GDAL. 
To enter GDAL codes I used the OSGeo4W Shell, which comes with QGIS. The command that I used to flip my map was:

gdal_translate -of netCDF -co WRITE_BOTTOMUP=NO my netcdf.nc output.nc

(see also [this](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_netcdf.html) short GDAL/netCDF introduction).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can use the GDAL configuration option GDAL_NETCDF_BOTTOMUP=[YES/NO] to convert from NetCDF to a geotiff, and get the resulting raster correctly oriented north-up. Try using [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) with the above option. See [here](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_netcdf.html) for some more details.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction! I had some work in between, but now I'm trying to fix it. 
I figured some things out about GDAL, but where should I find this GDAL configuration option? I tried to figure it out in Python, but so far no success. I managed to open a file and check its information/metadata, but I did not succeed in editing the file.

Comment: You just add to the command line `-co GDAL_NETCDF_BOTTOMUP=YES`

Comment: I used the OSGeo4W shell to try this:

gdal_translate GDAL GDAL_NETCDF_BOTTOMUP=YES <pathname to the file>. 

This gave me the following error: 
"Warning: The target file has a 'nc' extension, which is normally used by the GMT, netCDF drivers, but the requested output driver is GTiff. Is it really what you want ?"
ERROR 4: `GDAL_NETCDF_BOTTOMUP=YES' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name."
What am I doing wrong? Sorry for the questions, but I am new in this gdal format.

Comment: It should be something like: `gdal_translate -of GTiff -co GDAL_NETCDF_BOTTOMUP=YES <your netcdf.nc> <output.tif>` . Can I suggest you read the man page linked in the answer above.

Comment: I finally figured it out! I found that your code was a bit off for my specific case (not sure why). I used "gdal_translate -of netCDF -co WRITE_BOTTOMUP=NO <my netcdf.nc> <output.nc>" and it worked! Thank you for your help, it did sent me in the right direction.

Comment: try this gdal_translate -of GTiff --config GDAL_NETCDF_BOTTOMUP NO <your netcdf.nc> <output.tif>

Answer (score 1):

In `R` you can use `rotate` function

```
library(raster)
library(gdalUtils)


workdir <- "Your workind dir"
setwd(workdir)

ncfname <- "adaptor.mars.internal-1563580591.3629887-31353-13-1b665d79-17ad-44a4-90ec-12c7e371994d.nc"

# get the variables you want
dname <- c("v10","u10") 


# open using raster 
datasetName <-dname[1]
r <- raster(ncfname,  varname = datasetName)
r2 <- rotate(r)

writeRaster(r2,"wind.tif",driver = "TIFF")
```